# Make static analysis failure cause build failure on Travis

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci, static-analysis

I have an Objective-C iOS library building on Travis CI. I just enabled static analysis in my `.travis.yml` file, and it found an issue (a dead store), but it did not fail the build on Travis. Here is the relevant line in my `.travis.yml` (line-wrapped for readability):

```
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild analyze
    -workspace Example/BonMot.xcworkspace
    -scheme BonMot-Example
    -destination 'name=iPhone 6' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
```

What do I need to do in order to cause a warning in this line to fail the build on Travis CI? You can see the relevant pull request on my project [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot/pull/130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work out a way to make this work with some help from [this blog post](http://jonboydell.blogspot.ca/2013/02/clang-static-analysis.html). Here are the relevant parts of a sample `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c
rvm:
 - 2.2.4
osx_image: xcode7.3
install:
 - gem install xcpretty --no-rdoc --no-ri --no-document --quiet
 - export PYTHONUSERBASE=~/.local
 - easy_install --user scan-build
script:
 # use scan-build with --status-bugs to fail the build for static analysis warnings per http://jonboydell.blogspot.ca/2013/02/clang-static-analysis.html
 - export PATH="${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}" # I forget whether this was necessary. Try omitting it and see what happens!
 - set -o pipefail && scan-build --status-bugs xcodebuild analyze -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -destination 'name=iPhone 6' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way I could get this to work is to use the method detailed [here](http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/08/clang-static-analyzer)

Add these two parameters to your `xcodebuild` or `scan -x` command

```
CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT=plist-html \
CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT_DIR="$(pwd)/clang"
```

This will produce a HTML file if there are clang warnings.  So check for existence of this file.

```
if [[ -z `find clang -name "*.html"` ]]; then
    echo "Static Analyzer found no issues"
else
    echo "Static Analyzer found some issues"
    exit 123
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add `-Wunused-value` to the Other Warning Flags section of your build settings and set "Treat Warnings as Errors" to Yes.

Comment: I don't just want this particular warning to fail the build. I want _all_ static analysis warnings to fail the build. Would _treat warnings as errors_ count the blue static analysis findings as warnings?